# How to minimize an HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, post, postman, pubmed

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed

On the above URL, if I put "disease" in the search box, then click search. The I select "PMID List" to the right of "Format" ("Summary" is the original option).[image]

Then, I get a list like

```
30929330
30929328
30929327
30929322
30929319
30929318
30929317
30929314
30929313
30929312
30929308
30929289
30929282
30929260
30929256
30929252
30929235
30929234
30929230
30929224
```

The body of the corresponding HTTP POST request according to postman is the following. But I am not sure how to reduce the request to the simplest.

```
CitationManagerCustomRange:false
CitationManagerStartIndex:1
CollectionStartIndex:1
EmailCheck1:
EmailCheck2:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Cmd:displaychanged
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Db:pubmed
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.IdsFromResult:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastDb:pubmed
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastIdsFromResult:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastQueryKey:4
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastTabCmd:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkName:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkReadableName:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LinkSrcDb:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.QueryKey:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.TabCmd:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Term:disease
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.BMFacets:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetSubmitted:false
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_Facets.FacetsUrlFrag:filters=
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.PreviousPageName:results
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_PageController.SpecialPageName:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Answer:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Email:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailCount:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailFormat:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailHID:16gQ_jkjclApXw89-veCbHLjYX7grDUT9i4D2P3WVBMdCXEkWMCK0J4zPSHf4DW8SDEsE0P1NBR0ZceMk9rQdg7Yo_M0ZMZQJ
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailQueryKey:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailReport:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailSort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailStart:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailSubject:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.EmailText:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Holding:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.HoldingFft:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.HoldingNdiSet:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.Key:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.OToolValue:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.QueryDescription:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.EmailTab.SubjectList:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FFormat:docsum
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FSort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FileFormat:docsum
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.FileSort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Format:text
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastFormat:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastPageSize:20
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastPresentation:docsum
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.LastSort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PageSize:20
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Presentation:uilist
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevPageSize:20
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevPresentation:docsum
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PrevSort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Sort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.email_count:20
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.email_sort:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPageSize:20
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPresentation:uilist
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sSort:none
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.CurrPage:1
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage:1
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_Pager.cPage:1
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_ResultsController.ResultCount:4276777
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_ResultsController.RunLastQuery:
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.TimelineAdPlaceHolder.BlobID:NCID_1_35744195_130.14.18.97_9001_1554136263_544865890_0MetA0_S_MegaStore_F_1
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.TimelineAdPlaceHolder.CurrTimelineYear:
citman_count:20
citman_start:1
coll_start:1
email_add_text:
email_address:
email_format:docsum
email_start:1
email_subj:disease - PubMed
p$a:EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPresentation
p$l:EntrezSystem2
p$st:pubmed
term:disease
```

When I reduce it to the following, the return result is still the same.

```
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Cmd:displaychanged
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.Db:pubmed
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastQueryKey:4
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.Presentation:uilist
```

But if I remove this line, the result will be completely different. It seems that the website somehow remembers the history.

```
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.LastQueryKey:4
```

Could anybody show me how to get the minimal request so that I can use curl do download the list.

Comment: What was the rationale for not using the Entrez API?

Comment: It has certain limitation. But the web interface don’t.